# Removing execution of a recipe in a wrapper cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

We are developing a wrapper cookbook and we need to remove the execution of a recipe included (with `include_recipe`) in the recipe we add. Is there any way of doing it from the wrapper cookbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean there is an `include_recipe` statement in the library cookbook, and you want to remove it in the wrapper cookbook, then no, there is no way to do that.  The fact that you want to suggest there is either a bug in the library cookbook, or you are making a mistake in how you architect things.  Can you share a little more info, and maybe we can find a better solution?

### Here be dragons

If you want to be adventurous, you *might* be able to 'rewind' the effects of that unwanted recipe.  Either using the `rewind` cookbook, or simply using the `resources()` method, you can get a hold of the resources declared by the recipe, and then set their actions to `action :nothing`.  This will effectively un-run the recipe.  However, this should be an absolute last resort, in my opinion, as it's fraught with all sorts of gotchas and complexity.

Comment: The cookbook we are wrapping is https://github.com/caskdata/hadoop_cookbook, and the cookbook I'd like to remove is `hadoop::zookeeper` (because I have already a ZK cluster), which is included in `hadoop::hadoop_hdfs_zkfc` (added for installing ZKFailoverController). Maybe I can PR to the cookbook taking care of this situation.

Comment: Can you run a failover controller on a non-zookeeper node?

Comment: I think I can't. The recipe `hadoop::hadoop_hdfs_zkfc` includes `hadoop::zookeeper`

Comment: My point is, do you want to install hadoop_hdfs_zkfc without also installing zookeeper on that same node? If they are truly independent, then I'd put in a PR.

Comment: That's the case. Thanks for the tips.